# How can I present a Modal view using MvvmCross FormsPresenter (v4.4.0)?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I know how to write a custom presenter and I'm happy to do that if I need to.  However, I'm wondering if anybody's had success selectively presenting certain views (say, a Login View) as a modal to avoid all the NavigationStack wackiness that comes from presenting normally.  For now, I'm just working around by using my MvxContentPage's OnDisappearing to remove itself from the NavigationStack but that feels hacky to me.  Thoughts?

Comment: custom presenter it is. if you want it quick and dirty just check the viewmodel type and act accordingly. if you want a bit more sophisticated you can pass in a data structure to resolve the matching handler

Comment: There is no out of the box support for this scenario currently. As @woelliJ says, you will need to implement your own presenter, which presents a specific ViewModel modally.

Comment: Thanks guys - good to know I'm not missing something blindingly obvious :)